# If $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = e^{-x}\,f(x) + e^{x}\,f(-x)$, then is $f(x)$ even or odd?

Tags: calculus, integration, even-and-odd-functions

If $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = e^{-x}\,f(x) + e^{x}\,f(-x),$ then is $f(x)$ is even or odd? ($f(0) =0$ is given)

Clearly  $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is an even function. How can I check the nature of $f(x)$ from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$f(x)=\int_0^xf'(u)du$$therefore $$f(-x){=\int_0^{-x}f'(u)du\\=\int_0^x f'(-u)d(-u)\\=-\int_0^xf'(u)du\\=-f(x)}$$hence $f(x)$ is odd.

Comment: Is it true in general? What I mean is $f'$ is not always integrable. Edit: It's true, because $f$ is continuous, which means that $f'$ will be as well.

Comment: In fact there is a stricter condition that continuity for $f(x)$ such that its first order differentiation exists. A function is differentiable $n$ times over an interval if ${d^n\over dx^n}f(x)$ exists and is continuous over that interval.

Comment: What I meant is: $f$ is differentiable $\implies f$ is continuous $\implies x \mapsto e^{-x}f(x)+e^xf(-x)$ is continuous $\implies f'$ is continuous $\implies f'$ is Riemann-integrable. But we can also show that $f$ is $C^\infty$, because the RHS is differentiable $\implies$ LHS is differentiable.